# What is the purpose of double storing tags in the SO schema?

Tags: support, data-dump, data-explorer

I was looking at the schema and I noticed that there is a column titled `**tags**` in the posts table. What is the purpose of this column given that there is another table called `**PostTags**` that stores this information?

Comment: My guess is that the data dump schema doesn't accurately represent the actual database schema.

Comment: Or it's performance enhancement via denormalization.

Comment: @ Robert Harvey, can you please elaborate (bearing in mind that I am novice) how this could be a performance enhancement?

Comment: @Mel: `PostTags` would be used to look up posts by tag.  The `tags` column in the `Posts` table would be updated every time a tag is added or deleted from said post and is just a text representation of the current tags.  Or so I'm guessing.  The performance is gained when viewing lists of posts, because they don't require an addition query to display their tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Tags` field is a text field that stores a delimited list of tags for a question. I believe this was done to improve query performance when searching for questions with certain tags -- normalized schema vs. full-text index? I dunno which would win, though I suppose the latter since that appears to be what's in use.

The `PostTags` table exists only in Data Explorer (you'll notice it isn't in the data dump directly) as a normalized version of a question's tags, so you can do `JOIN`s in your queries, instead of doing text searches on the `Tags` field.

When running queries in Data Explorer, use the `PostTags` table exclusively. <strike>Data Explorer runs on SQL Azure so there's no full-text index on the `Tags` column.</strike> Data Explorer runs on SQL 2008, but there isn't a full-text index on the `Tags` column.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. But is it not more work to update the tags in the delimited list every time there's a change in the tags? You would have to select all the tags, concatenate them, and store them as a list... that sounds like a bit of work, no?

Comment: @Mel: Yes, it is, for sure. However, edits are far less frequent than searches. Moreover, in terms of time complexity, an edit is O(1), whereas a search increases in proportion to the number of questions. So they have to code around making searching very efficient.