# Really weird bug on "Unanswered > my tags", when I have no favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, encoding, my-tags

I wanted to look for some questions to answer, so I went to [`Unanswered Questions > my tags`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags). It came up with some really weird tags, as seen in this image:

> [image: unanswered questions > my tags screen shot]

[support](/questions/tagged/support), [winterbash-2013](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2013), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) are the tags in which I have the most posts. I also have [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217150/incorrect-reputation-in-dropdown) that has the tags [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation), and [achievements-dialog](/questions/tagged/achievements-dialog).

When I clicked on `|bug|reputation|achievements-dialog|`:

> [image: bug|reputation|achievements-dialog screen shot]

After I gave myself a favorite tag it acted as normal filtering the unanswered questions by that tag.

Comment: Hmm, seems to work just fine here.

Comment: @Bart Must be *caching*!

Comment: It's always caching. [feature-request] Have Community user post first answer on Meta. "It's caching".

Comment: @hims056 Ok, I'll (keep) trying that... note that my F5 key is wearing out.

Comment: Broken for me too, I have [tag:c#] in the list. Clicking on the tags gives a whole lot of results.

Comment: @hims056 How long is normal for this to resolve? It's been 50 mins (and countless Ctrl-F5s). Do we know anything about cache durations and so forth that might indicate a likely timespan?

Comment: Weird  it's really weird! It's take 3-4 minutes to resolve.

Comment: @hims056 Up to three hours now :-(

Comment: @Stijn Is it still broken for you?

Comment: [Yeah, it's still broken](http://i.imgur.com/AG7rUhz.png)

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Sometimes i get the same result, but hitting F5 multiple times updates the site.

Comment: Weird, even when editing my tags so I'm using the same as yours, it still works for me. What happens if you modify (add/remove) your favourite tags?

Comment: @Matt Good point. I tried adding a favourite tag (I didn't have any originally) and the page displayed. I've added that info to my question.

Comment: ... ahh, in which case, I can completely repo this if I have no favourite tags (like you; on meta and SO, but not other sites). Before, I assumed from the sidebar in the screenshot that those were your favourite tags (which is what I meant by me trying to repo with your tags).

Comment: I repro this as well on IE11/Chrome and FF

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of those is Portuguese for Winterbash ...

Comment: I don't have any favorites on Meta and with Chome, I got 6 English-version tags (my 6 highest scoring tags).

Comment: Reproduced on [beer SX](http://beer.stackexchange.com) with `firefox 26.0`. Probably reproducable on all SX sites. ![screenshot](s14.postimg.org/3s0yss5s1/bug.png)

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce this (Firefox 27.0).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It appears to be fixed!

Comment: I just noticed it's working again for me, it wasn't working yet a week ago. Is yours fixed too?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, it's working for me now too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, Nick fixed this back on February 12th.

The cause involved a change to how [denormalized tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69844/what-is-the-purpose-of-double-storing-tags-in-the-so-schema) are delimited in the database: turns out that some people actually *use* characters like ö and é - in *words!* So the crazy query that figures out what your top tags are needed to be more sensitive to this sort of madness.

(or I'm making all this up; that's like a *month* ago now, ancient history, lost in the mists of time!)